# Webdriver/Selenium 2.0 API not working with Firefox 4

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Should I be doing anything different if I am using Selenium2.0/WebDriver with Firefox 4? I have code that works with Firefox 3.x(3.8 I guess) but the same code does not work with FIrefox 4.0 on Windows 7 Home.

My Page object:

```
@FindBy(how= How.LINK_TEXT, using="Add Program")
@CacheLookup
private WebElement addProgram;
```

HTML :

```
<div class="form_btn"><a
    href="/programs/program/addProgram"> <span>Add
Program</span></a></div>
```

I am using PageFactory for initialization. The same HTML/CSS and Java code works for Firefox.
 3.x

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: What is the error that you are seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not going to work with firefox 4 [jssh in firefox 4](https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/820677)
You'll need to use a different method like [watir webdriver](http://watirmelon.com/2010/04/10/watir-selenium-webdriver/)

For a firefox addon you'll just have to wait till the developers release a different addon.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I actually tried it with Firefox 3.6 as well I am getting the same problem. Must be a local issue. Will do some more plumbing and get back. Thanks.

Comment: This question is probably no longer an issue since Firefox is on Version 12.  For anyone working with Selenium and Firefox, given the pace of Firefox releases and occasional issues with Selenium, we started to use the corporate ESR version to better control the pace of upgrades.